# React native: 'require' is not defined

Tags: react-native, require

I'm using clean project and I cannot use **require** in any part of my code, for example here in the Image:

```
<Image
  style={styles.stretch}
  source={require('./img/favicon.png')}
/>
```

or in any other part like here using the react-native-router-flux plugin, I want to overwrite the back button image but I cannot change it because 'require' is not defined.

```
<Scene backButtonImage={require('./custom_icon.png')} />
```

This is my **package.json**

```
  {
  "name": "CleanProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.40.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.37.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "eslint": "^3.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "18.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.0-rc.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Hi, may I see the error message?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably just a config issue with your Linter. It should build just fine. If you want to remove the error in your developer tool and are using ESLint, at the top of your file try adding:

```
/* global require */
```